# Django CreateView not creating on submit of form

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce

In my views.py:

```
class DatasetRequestCreateView(CreateView):
    model = DatasetRequest
    form_class = DatasetRequestForm
    template_name = 'engine/datasetrequest_create.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("datasetrequest_detail", kwargs={
            'pk': str(self.kwargs['pk']),
            'slug': str(self.kwargs['slug'])})

    def form_valid(self, form):

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user
        f.save()
        # dsr = f.save()
        # dsr.votes.up(self.request.user.pk)

        return super(DatasetRequestCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

## forms.py

```
class DatasetRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DatasetRequest
        exclude = ('creator', 'vote_score', 'num_vote_up',
               'num_vote_down', 'slug', 'best_dataset_entry', 'is_paid')
```

Relevant urlpatterns in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# datasetrequest views
    path('dataset-request/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/',
         views.DatasetRequestDetailView.as_view(), name='datasetrequest_detail'),
    path('dataset-request/create/', 
         login_required(views.DatasetRequestCreateView.as_view()), name='datasetrequest_create'),
    path('dataset-request/update/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/',
         login_required(views.DatasetRequestUpdateView.as_view()), name='datasetrequest_update'),
    path('dataset-request/delete/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/',
         login_required(views.DatasetRequestDeleteView.as_view()), name='datasetrequest_delete'),

    path('dataset-request/pay/<int:dsr_pk>/',
         login_required(views.pay_for_dataset_request), name='datasetrequest_pay'),
]
```

Page in question: http://datafix.io/dataset-request/create
Log in with username "test" and password "djangohelp" or create your own account.

To recreate the error, enter a title, description, and (int) reward and try to submit the form. It will basically just refresh the page without having created the form.

DatasetRequestCreateView worked fine before I integrated django-wysiwyg with tinymce into the form. Not sure what is wrong. Docs are on their readme: https://github.com/pydanny-archive/django-wysiwyg

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `v` field is mandatory? Is dta save into database when click on submit?

Comment: Could you post `DatasetRequestForm` and `urls.py`?

Comment: posted DatasetRequestForm and urls.py @WillKeeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your form is invalid and you are not displaying any server-side validation errors. The error messages you see when you leave e.g. the `title` field empty are rendered by the browser because the field has an HTML5 `required` attribute.

Make sure you correctly [render validation errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages) in your template by adding `{{ field.errors }}` for each field and also `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

This should give you an idea what is going wrong.